# How do you use an ArrayAdapter for a HorizontalListView

Tags: android

I'm currently using a HorizontalListView which I add items to by using the addView method. 
Is there a way to populate a HorizontalListView with an ArrayAdapter in the same way as you can for a ListView, which is always vertical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you meant you are using HorizontalScrollView, because there is no such thing as HorizontalListView. If you want to accomplish that your best shot is to create that type of ListView yourself, ie. by subclassing `AbsListView` or `AdapterView`. Or you could just use somebody elses code, like this [Horizontal ListView](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34) :)

Comment: My bad: yes, I meant HorizontalScrollView. Thanks for the information: very helpful!

Comment: @ZhDev, please update the link you have provided. its not working as of today(19th-Sep-2016)